# How to create webfonts compatible with glyphicons-halflings?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, gruntjs, webfonts

I want to create a webfont with grunt-webfont. The glyphs should have the same dimensions like the glyphicon-halflings used by twitter bootstrap.

My problem is that my icons look greater or smaller or do not match the same baseline.

Is there anywhere a svg base template I can to create my icons? Do I have to set values for fontHeight and descent?